# Django Haystack filtering

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I have two django filters which I want to use to filter out posts but one post can have many categories so I've put categories in a list in the URL. Now here comes the problem - I need to filter by the title of the post and by category but I need to do it in a way which will enable me to get the union of the categories checked. Here is the current code:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()

if 'title' in request.GET and request.GET['title'] != '':
   sqs = sqs.filter_and(title=request.GET['title'])

if 'category' in request.GET and request.GET['category'] != '':
    catlist = request.GET.getlist('category')

    for i in catlist:
        sqs = sqs.filter_or(category=i)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

More info: Django 1.4.1, Django-Haystack 1.2.7

EDIT:

I did what you suggested (used __in):

```
if 'title' in request.GET and request.GET['title'] != '':
   sqs = sqs.filter_and(title=request.GET['title'])

if 'category' in request.GET and request.GET['category'] != '':
    catlist = request.GET.getlist('category')

    sqs = sqs.filter_or(category__in=catlist)
```

But still no luck - I can't search by field and by categories. Searching only by category seems to be working but when those two fields are inputed together they don't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `django.db.models.Q` and union operations or `__in`

```
sqs.filter(Q(category=i) | Q(category=j))
```

(you can union the Q's before submitting into `filter`)

Or use __in:

```
sqs.filter(category__in=catlist)
```

I'll name some packages without linking, since googling them is simple.

Try debugging and runnig queries from shell. To debug, install ipdb and add this line in the view in the place where you want to stop.

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

You'll see the shell in the console window (not in the browser). Type `h` or `help` in the debug shell. Try django debug toolbar, it can help debugging the queires (it has SQL debug panel), works in the browser.

Also try making queries in the shell. Install django-extensions and use shell_plus:

```
manage.py shell_plus
```

IPython will also be helpful. In the shell, try running queries and see the results. Only when you're sure they work as you want, put the logic in the view. Otherwise, debugging by refreshing the page is a very long road.

If you need ether a category, or title to match, do this:

```
q = Q()
title = request.GET.get('title'):
if title:
    q |= Q(title__contains=title)  # q = q | Q(...)

if request.GET.get('category'):
    for cat in request.GET.getlist('category'):
        q |= Q(category=cat)

sqs = SearchQuerySet.filter(q)
```

Comment: I used the second solution but with no luck. See my edited question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Looks like the title is not in any of those categories. If you combine both, then the items must have both a category in the list and exactly that title. If you need just either of those conditions met, then use `Q(field=value) | Q(...) ...`

Comment: Plus one for the advise to use shell for debugging.